No Android WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, with ALL_FILE_ACCESS granted?
I have a music player app (that only I use, it is not in Google Play nor it will ever be) with the following Manifest permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

The device reports that the app also have ALL_FILES_ACCESS permission granted (I want it that way).
Still, the app reports that it has no WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission when I try the usual requestPermissions.
However, there is no permission in the App settings regarding storage to be allowed, and it says No permissions denied.
I tried forcing with adb shell like this:
appops set --uid myApp.xvfmusic WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow

and the app still keeps asking for permissions...
Why is the thing asking me to set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and why there is no such permission to set in the app config?

If you have ALL_FILES_ACCESS, why are you asking for permission that does not exist anymore? What makes you think you need any additional permissions beyond ALL_FILES_ACCESS?

Recent android versions the write external storage permission is ignored and never granted. if you have the manage eternal storage permission granted you dont need to worry about the read/write

So WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not exist anymore?? I had no idea, and Studio did not warn me about that. My app reports no build problems, and no problems under inspection! (My app has several years, and each Android iteration asks me to tweak here and there, once and again. I do not remember why I set each one.)

Actually, I have exactly the same problem with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE too. Is it also ignored?

If this is an app just hur you you should present more details on the phone(s) it will run on, because most of the mentioned storage permissions are irrelevant on recent Android versions.

I am running it in a Galaxy Note 10 Lite. Which permissions are now irrelevant? I wonder why Android Studio didn't tell anything....... but not surprised. :-/

This is why you should always look through the API changes for different android versions, its not android studios job to warn you about api changes https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-11

Yes, of course we all look, but to certain extent, and we don't keep it in our memory. Either the code inspection tools should do all the checks, or they should be removed. If Android Studio code inspection, made by Google itself, does not find even trivial deprecations like this, why should you suspect there is one, and one so trivial to catch? Moreover, not all of us have so much time. Android is a nightmare for devs that do not make a living with Android, changing a ton of stuff each 6 months.


"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is deprecated (and is not granted) when
targeting Android 13+. If you need to write to shared storage, use the
MediaStore"
As of Android 13, if you need to query or interact with MediaStore or
media files on the shared storage, you should be using instead one or
more new storage permissions:

android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO


Looks like your device is running Android 13+ and that's why you cant request "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE supersedes WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & allows broad access to external storage. You don't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if you already have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted.
To publish apps with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, you'll need clear justification for requesting it, otherwise the app will be rejected. Since you're not publishing the app on Google Play, it's fine. But those who think MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is the alternative to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, they're wrong. If they can't clearly justify the need to request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (which most apps can't), their apps will be rejected. Their choice should be either app specific external storage (Android/data/package-name) access or the ones described in documentation above
